# How to call a JS function after every 24 hours and save the result with timestamp in a cookie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, cookies, dom-events

I want a function that'll read a cookie file or cookie and call another function and save the timestamp with the result. 
Condition: It'll only call the function if-

- The cookie doesn't exist or is empty
- It's been more than 24 hours

Comment: You probably want a web service at some point but I'd suggest you have a look at http://xyproblem.info/ before you dive too deep into a very specific and unusual solution

Comment: So this can't be done without opening the browser?

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can pay someone to visit your page every 24 hours... Maybe a cron job would do the trick, no PHP for that. Without a browser makes me think that you can remove the jquery and the dom tags

Comment: Without a browser, where would you expect the cookie to be saved/accessed?

Comment: Now is the question correct?

Comment: Everyone please chk , I have edited the question

Comment: @Vyom your question is still not correct. We don't know what you have tried. It seems that you fell into the XY problem. Please read this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Retrieve new results without PHP or a browser? What exactly is going to retrieve them? Other than a cron job? Please take a step back and tell us what your actual problem is; don't ask us how to implement the bad solution you've come up with.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that a program runs reliably, the traditional approach for this kind of function is to have a cron job, run a daemon, or at worst, run a script on a server.

However, you intend to run this on the browser, which is not impossible as long as you maintain that browser window open and active. You can use [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to invoke a function every 24 hours. `new Date()` will let you grab a timestamp, and [here is more info on how to manipulate cookies in javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp), as it is unclear what your exact intention is with cookie reading/saving.

Having said that, for reliable execution of the job for an extended period of time, reconsidering your architecture may be the real solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

`setInterval(function(){
  var yourCookieValue = new Date().getTime();
  setCookie("yourCookie", yourCookieValue, 30); }, 
  1000*60*60*24);`